# How to open a route url in new tab in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to open router.navigate(["/url"]) in new tab. If I give, target="_blank"in link, it opens a blank new page, without any data. Otherwise, it opens in same window with the data from server.
I would link to achieve the same functionality in anew tab. How to achieve that?

Regards,
Meenakshi Jyotsna

Comment: Won't work. The app has to be loaded seperately in a new tab. There is no functionality to pass data from one tab to another. A browser tab is nothing else then a new browser window. The only thing you could do is open your app in a new tab and passing the data via url queries, localstorage or something like that

Answer (score 4):

Angular doesn't support navigating to a new tab , please use  window.open to do this

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found luck with adding the following to a link to open in a new tab.

```
li(*ngFor="let link of listOfLinks")
.test-link
  a.menu-item(
    [href]="link.href"
    rel="noopener noreferrer"
    target="_blank"
    ) {{link.name}}
```

The `rel="noopener no referrer"` somehow allows the `target="_blank` to work, not 100% sure how, but give it a try!